# How to make ant put a package directive in several source files?

Tags: java, ant, antlr4

I'm using Antlr4 to build a parser and I'm using Netbeans as an IDE and `ant` as a build system. Ant runs Antlr which generates a `parser.java` and `lexer.java` in the project's `src/` directory.

They both need a package directive, and so I have to add it by hand.

Is there a way to prepend a line of text to all source files in a directory with Ant? Or are there any other solutions to this? (Maybe with Antlr?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combinaison of the `-o` option for antlr4 command line and `@header{...}` in your grammar:

- `-o` allows you to specify the output directory where all output will be generated,
- `@header{...}` will insert the code you write into `{..}` as your generated code header so you can put your package declaration into this block.

for example:

```
grammar myGrammar;

@header {
    package my.package;
}
...
```

If you don't want to tie your grammar to a specific language, you can use the `-package` option (allows you to specify a package or namespace for the generated files) and remove the package declaration from your `@header{...}` code.

Answer (score 0):

There's an odd caveat where @header {...} in a grammar for a combined lexer+parser works. However for separate lexer and parser grammar files each has to have the header declared as

```
@lexer::header { ... }
// or 
@parser::header { ... }
```

or else only the parser will have a header added (that is the caveat).

Also, as mentioned by Vincent there is a command line option, but that same caveat applies.

Comment: You're right, if you have separate files for lexer and parser, you have to specify where the header should go. I supposed you used combined grammar and lexer. However, you can use `@parser::header` and `@lexer::header` in the grammar file only, this lets your lexer "grammar independent".